# How to get value of a Control Specific property in CodedUI?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I have a scenario where my some part of code depends on value of TEXT property (a control specific type property).

Please provide help on how to get value of TEXT property.

Answer (score 2):

Controls that have this property (Text) exposes it publicly and it can be accessed programatically, 
for example:

```
WpfEdit editControl = new WpfEdit();
editControl .Text = " Some text";
```

or alternatively:

```
string content = editControl .Text;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Nikolay..! But I'm still confused. Do you advice to find out Type of Control to which TEXT property is associated. Am i correct? If this is the way then can you guide me how to find out the same?

Comment: (barak not nikolay:) - this property is public and every control that has it exposes it. my example shows how to access it. What type of control you need to get the Text property from?